# Удаление файлов на сервере php

Tags: php

На сервере приблизительно 30 сайтом и в каждой папке файлы с мусором (вирусом), я знаю размер и название файлов(они повторяются), пробвал написать код на PHP чтоб проверил каждую папку и удалил файл с параметрами "file_name" и "file_size"

Пробовал следующий код

```
rrmdir('site');

function rrmdir($dir){
    $file_name = "406.php";
    $file_size = 314;
    if (is_dir($dir)){
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                $file_delete = dirname(__FILE__) . $file;
                unlink($file_delete);
            }
        closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}
```

Но получаю ошибку

Warning: unlink(site\lending.loc): Permission denied in on line site\lending.loc 12

задача следующая

Надо проверить все папки в указаной папке и удалить файлы с указаными параметрами - название и размер

Буду благодарный за помощь

Comment: необходимо запустить скрипт под тем пользователем у которого есть права на удаление всех указанных файлов (ошибка говорит именно о недостатке прав)

Comment: тестирую код локально на OpenServer, для теста создал 1 папку с вложеными 3 папками где тоже есть вложение и в каждой папке по 2 файла (который надо удалить и просто чистый).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо хотя бы добавить условие в цикле:

```
if($file == $file_name && filesize($dir.'/'.$file) == $file_size)
```

, чтобы проверить что файл вообще нужно удалять. и вот тут:

```
$file_delete = dirname(__FILE__) . $file;
```

dirname(**FILE**) указывает на директорию в которою лежит файл с методом. Т е читаете вы один файл, а удалить пытаетесь другой. Попробуйте так:

```
rrmdir('site');

function rrmdir($dir){
    $file_name = "406.php";
    $file_size = 314;
    if (is_dir($dir)){
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
               if($file == $file_name && filesize($dir.'/'.$file) == $file_size){    
                   $file_delete = $dir . '/' . $file;
                   unlink($file_delete);
               }
            }
        closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 1):

Дешево и сердито: в командной строке:

```
find -type f -name '406.php' -size 314c -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Если не умеете в консоли, сделайте скриптик `del.php`, но должна быть включена функция [shell_exec](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.execution.php):

```
`find -type f -name '406.php' -size 314c -exec rm -f {} \;`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю полностью код может кому понадобится

```
rrmdir('site'); /*папка где будет выполнятся действия*/


function rrmdir($dir){
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir"){
          rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
        }  
        else {
            $file_name = "406.php"; /*Название файла*/
            $file_size = 314; /*Размер файла в байтах*/
            if (is_dir($dir)){
                if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
                    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                       if($file == $file_name && filesize($dir.'/'.$file) == $file_size){    
                           $file_delete = $dir . '/' . $file;
                           unlink($file_delete);
                       }
                    }
              closedir($dh);
           }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```